# Read new update from database and then execute PHP code - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm currently studying a telegram chatbot and I got this idea that I want the bot to send only new data if there is new data in my database which is `MySQL` and it won't execute the `PHP` code if there is no new data. But I can't figure out how to do it, for now, I use the meta `http-equiv= "refresh"`. Is there any other method that does something that I need to implement?

I tried to use AJAX long polling method but I don't really understand how to implement it on my project, but I think it might solve my problem. And I already tried to auto-refresh the page every 10 minutes, it works but it will spam the chat with the same data every 10 minutes if there is no new data.

## For now this is my code for executing the chatbot so that it will send my data.

```
<?php
$orang = $db->query('SELECT time_stamp,group_name, message, nvalue, old_svalue, inactive_timestamp, ack_timestamp
FROM alarm ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 2');


//$arrayAll = [];
foreach($orang as $orn){
    $data = implode(" ",$orn);
    $arrayAll[] = $data;
}
//new update function

//execute dibawah
if($orn["nvalue"] < 30){
    echo "Tidak dikirim";
}else{
$arrayAll = implode("\n", $arrayAll);

$response = $telegram->sendMessage([
    'chat_id' => "$idChat",
    'text' => "\n$arrayAll",
    'parse_mode' => 'HTML'
  ]);
}

?>
```

## This is my HTML for showing the data on the database

```
<body> 
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Message</th>
            <th>Group Name</th>
            <th>Time Stamp</th>
        </tr>
        
        <?php 
    foreach($orang as $org){    
    ?>
    <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $org["message"];?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $org["group_name"];?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php echo $org["time_stamp"];?>
            </td>
            <?php       
            }       
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you want to execute the PHP code every 10 minutes and only select rows with timestamps after the last execution. Is that right? Is the HTML display intended to show only the "new data" as well?

Comment: yes, but I want to execute the PHP code if there is only a new data in the database and if there isn't any new data it won't get executed.

Comment: I forgot to add the query for the newest data, but I use ORDER BY time_stamp DESC LIMIT 5 for the HTML and for the chatbot I use the same query but with only 2 LIMIT

Comment: Watch this comment system, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Gj_zWCHTIk which is using realtime ajax load. or here php sleep https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

Comment: _"but I want to execute the PHP code if there is only a new data in the database and if there isn't any new data it won't get executed"_ - that doesn't make the most sense ... you need to execute _something_, to check whether there _are_ new entries in the database. Whether you proceed with actually generating any new output _after_ that check, is up to you.

Comment: what I meant by the PHP code is the send message function.

Comment: @DLK I've tried the suggestion but it can't be implemented on my app, because that video has something to trigger some sort of 'mini refresh'. In my case there is nothing to be triggered like button or anything. basically I get the data from another tool and the tool send the data to my database. And then I show the data on the web app that I create and then send it to telegram chatbot